# How can I update the web3.js of Geth?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

Web3.js has so many newer versions than one of Geth.
I want to use the 1.2.0 version (or newer) web3 with Geth.
When compiling, can I replace the old version with any newer version?

Comment: geth is an implementation of ethereum and web3.js is a library to programatically interact with the Ethereum network from a js application. can you make your question more clear?

Comment: In short you need to recompile geth. But it might not work even if you recompile it, the javascript interpreter used by geth is quite limited.